# What exactly is stored in dynamic linking

Tags: operating-systems

I read that in dynamic linking we store the references to the the methods of the library , but a library is essentially a collection of files , and every file will have some code in it , so the reference is stored of which file?

Answer (score 1):

A library is a single file, containing compiled code. It needn't be structured as the original files. The references are to all functions that were defined (and explicitly exported).

Answer (score 1):

When you include an header, you declare to the compiler that you defined the functions found in the header somewhere. The compiler doesn't know where but it trusts you to provide those definitions during linking.

During compilation, the compiler compiles every source file independently. Each source file has to be self contained and contain at least all declarations for the functions you call. For functions that are not defined, the compiler leaves `call` instructions to those functions with an undefined address to reach them. It also leaves the symbol of the function (its name) along with a relocation method (see program counter or PC relative addresssing, absolute addressing, code models, etc). The exact way that it passes this information to the linker varies between executable file formats.

Once you call the linker, you have to provide all libraries that you call into (associated with each header that you include) including dynamic libraries. Otherwise, the linker complains that it didn't find the definition for certain of these functions and is thus not able to relocate the call instructions. The linker's job is to take all compiled object code files (unlinked code made by the compiler) and arrange them in proper order in code blocks with call instructions fixed to jump at the proper address for functions defined in other object code files or libraries. The standard libraries are often simply added by default to the linker's command line so that's why you might not need to add them manually in most cases.

For your question, in dynamic linking the reference is stored in the object file after compilation but the final executable contains a string which is the path of the library. The linker which is called after compilation doesn't yet know where this library is loaded so it leaves a path to the library as you provide yourself when you call it. The os then either loads that library in RAM anywhere it deems appropriate and fixes the relocations before jumping to your first instruction or, if the library is already loaded, it fixes the relocations directly and makes sure to adjust page tables to make sure the library is found in the address space of your program.